# Why does gnuplot ignore the given time range in plot?

Tags: time, range, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 5.1 (CVS) and I have time data in a file. I'm using

```
set xdata time
set timefmt  '(format in datafile)'
set format x '(format to display)'
```

This works perfectly fine when doing

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:2
```

But when doing

```
plot ['(format in datafile)':] 'datafile' using 1:2
```

gnuplot is ignoring the range. I get no error, it simply plots the whole datafile instead of starting at the given xmin (but all numbers and time strings are fully correct, only that gnuplot does not limit the plotted line to the given range).

I also tested it with the explicit full syntax giving the max time in the data:

```
plot [x='(format in datafile)':'(format in data)'] 'datafile' using 1:2
```

This does not work either, it plots simply the whole data available in the data.

Specifying the range via `set xrange ['(format in data)':]` does work, however! But I need to plot several lines in different ranges, so I need to be able to specify the range at plot-time! See gnuplot manual page 98, this should be working.

**How to get gnuplot to limit the time based data range on plotting? Or did I discover a bug?**

Comment: Yes, that looks like a bug.